# How to split this into tokens?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have this data:

```
/some test/ -> next data
prev<-/now/->/how about this/ 
asd<-/rege\/x/
/\/\//
/\\/
/^\d+$/ <- /\./
/\./ -> /\d/
```

and I want to split it info tokens `\w+|/.*?/`, `<-`, `->` but `->` and `<-` can't apear inside `/here/`
I tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/rVKter/3), but it fails in this case `/\/\//`.

```js
const data = `/some test/ -> next data
prev<-/now/->/how about this/ 
asd<-/rege\/x/
/\/\//
/\\/
/^\d+$/ <- /\./
/\./ -> /\d/`

console.log(data.split(/\s*(\w+|\/.*?\/\B)\s*/).filter(x => x != ""))
```

What sould I do in my regex to cover this part?

Comment: Something like [`\s*(\w+|\/[^\/\\]*(?:\\.[^\/\\]*)*\/)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/EK8Yun/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's what i wanted thank you very much :)

Comment: I guess you could go with escape anything approach, but then you lose sight of where the delimiter begins. Without that, your tokens are shifted [https://regex101.com/r/EK8Yun/4](https://regex101.com/r/EK8Yun/4). And the total parse is meaningless ... While parsing Perl `$v =~ \//x/;` is an error.

Comment: Actually `$v =~ \//x\/;`  should throw because there's no valid token here only `/^\w+$/`, `'<-'`, `'->'`and `/^\/.*?\/$/` are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** you cannot have an escaped `/` char before an unescaped `/` that starts a `/.../` substring, you may use

```
/\s*(\w+|\/[^\/\\]*(?:\\.[^\/\\]*)*\/)\s*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EK8Yun/2)

If a line break char (like CR or LF) can be escaped, you will need to replace `.` with `[\s\S]` / `[^]` to match *any* character.

NOTE: `\/[^\/\\]*(?:\\.[^\/\\]*)*\/` matches...

- `\/` - a `/`
- `[^\/\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `/` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^\/\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\\.` - an escaped char
  - `[^\/\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `/` and `\`
- `\/`  - a `/` char